# How to work around cell arrays that exceeds memory capacity?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, loading, cell-array, memory-efficient

I have a problem with insufficient memory (RAM) when I am reading metrological data (GRIB files), amounting to 35 GB of data, into a matlab cell array.

How can I work around my RAM-restrictions when I load big data sets?

I have tried to preallocate the cell-array, but that does not help. It stops at 70% loading of the data set.

Here is the FOR-loop that errors:

% load grib files

```
for ii = 1:number_files
    waitbar(ii/number_files,h);
    file_name = [fname,'\',num2str(ii),'.grb'];
    grib_struct = read_grib([file_name],-1);
    Temp{ii} = single(grib_struct(1,1).fltarray);
    Rad_direct{ii} = single(grib_struct(1,2).fltarray);
    Rad_diff{ii} = single(grib_struct(1,3).fltarray);
    fclose('all');
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously you can't load **35 GB** of data into your memory! You'll have to find a way to selectively load data for your computation, and then remove it afterwards to make room for more data. You probably don't need _all_ of the data at once for your computation.

Comment: it's not that obvious. the file size on disk does not have to correspiond to memory footprint in matlab. by using single it looks like the dataset size is already reduced by half, which is probly why it stops at 70 % rather than less than 50%, still if you need more data than can fit in memory, MW introduced http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/datastore.html

Comment: Thanks, guys! Each cell represents a coordinate system, 657x665, i.e. 436905 elements and I need those for further analysis. I will check out datastore, but I don't see how I can apply it at first sight - I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matfile` command to work directly on the file system. It stores every data you put into directly on the file system. It will be slow, but it is possible.